# laravel showing error when vite not loaded (how to start larvel just with php artisan serve)

Tags: laravel, vite

I am new to Laravel and I start my Laravel project using `php artisan serve` but I found that I also have to load Vite from another command prompt using `npm run dev` in order to make Laravel project run properly is there any method to autoload Vite when I do `php artisan serve`

[image]

**when Vite is loaded my code works correctly**

[image]

**scripts in package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
```

Comment: Remove `@vite('resources/js/app.js')` (or something like that) in ypur blade file if you don't use it

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka i did remove as u asked  but for me the code was bit differnt   `@viteReactRefresh
    @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])` i think the react ui package has caused the issue but the probelem is the css for my login and registration is not loading

Comment: It may differ depends on your [needs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#loading-your-scripts-and-styles) or basic setup. `@vite` directive will inject styles and scripts from manifest file. With `php artisan serve` you do not compile assets but just running the server - so there is no manifest at first. Once being compiled everything will be OK. You need either to build assets (`npm run <command>`) to use `@vite` or include scripts, styles on your own. Laravel throws this Exception when your demand to include assets (using `@vite`) but they're missing

Answer (score 1):

###### Cause of Problem:

In older versions of `Laravel` we were using `laravel-mix` package but now `laravel` js compiling engine is shifted to `vite` and it is much more faster.

In the case of `mix` engine whenever we run `npm run dev` generate compiled js code in `public/js` directory. and due to it we need to refresh page manually everytime.

But now In `vite` when you run `npm run dev` it just starts a `vite server` that continuously monitor your changes and reflect those changes on screen immediately. but it's not generate `compiled js` files in `public/js` directory

So, when your `vite` server not running it shows above error.

##### Solution:

If you want to run `laravel` without runing `vite server` by `npm run dev` you will need to run `npm run build`. It will generate `compiled js` files in `public/js` directory so then you will not have need to run `vite server`.

> **Caution:** if you run `npm run dev` after the `npm run build` command your compiled templates will be removed. So, you will need to run `npm run build` once again after stopping `vite server` which is running using `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

```
npm run dev
```

with vite is basically what

```
npm run watch
```

used to do back with mix.

If you focus on your back-end, try to run prod instead, so that your main page works while you deal with laravel.

Once you get to front-end work and need your js running, you need to have vite up during development. At any point you can stop the process, run a quick prod build and get back to whatever you want.

Comment: i think u have mistaken the question what i am trying to achive is that to remove the need of tunning npm command for running my project `@viteReactRefresh     @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])` with this code commaded i was able to make it run just using php artisan sevre but my login scrrens does not have css now

Answer (score 0):

npm and artisan are two different tools that have nothing to do with each other. They need to run seperately.

You can extend your *package.json* to automatically start both with *npm run serve*:

```js
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "serve": "php artisan serve & npm run dev"
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because of your  Node version. Check your Node Version

```
node -v
```

if it's below 16, you should upgrade it to the latest one then run

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

Comment: my node verision is   v16.17.0

Comment: pls read the question carefuly my code does  work when i do npm run dev